# PHP stream_socket_client and facebook chat

Tags: php, facebook, xmpp

```
$fp         = stream_socket_client("tcp://chat.facebook.com:5222", $errno, $errstr, 20);

fwrite($fp, '<stream:stream to="chat.facebook.com" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" version="1.0" />' . PHP_EOL);

$temp1      = fgets($fp);

fwrite($fp, '<auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM"></auth>');

$temp2      = fgets($fp);

fclose($fp);

die(var_dump( $temp1, $temp2 ));
```

What is causing the $temp2 `false` result?

```
    string(365) "<?xml version="1.0"?><stream:stream id="247B12CF" from="chat.facebook.com" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0" xml:lang="en"><stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features></stream:stream>"
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `stream:stream` line should just be a start tag, not a full element.  Remove the / as the next-to-last character in your first `fwrite` call.  The server is disconnecting you when you send a full root element rather than a start tag.